# Does placing sync.Mutex in package level variable has any effects on package level maps?

Tags: go, locking, mutex

Would calling mu.Lock() in one of the following functions lock the package level accCache map?

```golang
package cache

import (
    "sync"
)

type CachedAccount struct {
    Id       string
    Expires  int64
}


var accCache = make(map[string]CachedAccount)

var mu sync.Mutex


func addAccount...
func getAccount...
```

Comment: The mutex locks the "block of code" between its lock & unlock. It doesn't lock variables. i.e. the code between a lock & unlock of a mutex will not be executed by more than one goroutine at the same time.

Comment: No, two completely unrelated variables don't do anything to each other, regardless of their visibility inside/outside of a package. The map is not related to the mutex in any way.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `Lock` on a variable of type `sync.Mutex` does nothing except for ensuring that any other goroutine which calls `Lock` on the same variable will suspend its execution until some other goroutine calls `Unlock` on that same variable.

That is, your line of thinking is wrong: a mutex does not *by itself* protect any program state. Instead, it's only a certain means of explicitly serializing access to some parts of the program's state.
Which parts are these—is decided by which code accesses them, and all that code should use some agreed-upon mechanism of serializing such access (it can be a mutex or something else).

Specifically because of this, it's possible to introduce data races in the code: if not all code paths which access the same parts of the program's state use the same synchronization mechanisms, a data race condition exists.